# Как подключить DLL C# в проекте на Java?

Tags: java, c#, jna

Нужно подключить написанную на c# dll в проекте на java. Было бы не плохо если показали рабочий пример.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743715/how-to-call-into-net-dll-from-java

Comment: Спасибо помогло